# Setup Java Project to a Web-app using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have developed a board game with Maven, where I have use SpringBoot to run on a Web app. Now I'm in the process of figuring out how to actually connect my SpringBoot (frontend) with my Maven board game (backend). I've downloaded my SpringBoot project using [this site](https://spring.io/quickstart).

I have searched and searched for a guide explaining that, but I couldn't really find a guide for my problem.

How will it be possible to connect my existing Maven Project to Springboot, so I can set it up as Web app?

Here's my DemoApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

To sum it all up; my purpose is to make my project into a web application. And this has to be done using springboot, but my question is how will the two parts be able to be connected?

Comment: Maven is a project manager tool, that is used to manage build, docs and other sections of your project. SpringBoot on the other hand is a framework to simplify development of application using Java programming language and is based on top of Spring.

You are mixing terms here -- what is used to implement your web app (board game) and how are you planning to use SpringBoot with? As deployment application to host your web-server like Tomcat to be able to run you board game implementation?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes, I am planning to use it as deployment application to host my server.

Comment: You can create the back-end with Spring Boot like your code snippets. The back-end can provide a REST API. And in the front-end you have, for example, a React application that calls your backend, your REST-API.

Comment: @Twistleton, that's what I wanted, can you please refer me to a page?

Comment: Here is a simple example on implementation of backend REST API with SpringBoot: https://www.twilio.com/blog/create-rest-apis-java-spring-boot (include db, services, testing via Postman etc).

Comment: From the fabulous Andy Olsen: http://olsensoft.com/enterprise-react/